# Vim: delete up to nth specified character

Tags: vim, vi

I'm pretty new to vim and I just learned that you can use `dtx` or `dfx` to delete up to `x` and up to and including `x` respectively. Is there a way to choose which occurrence of `x` to delete to?
For example, if I have the line

```
peter piper picked a pickled pepper
```

and I wanted to delete up to the fifth `p` to obtain

```
pickled pepper
```

What commands would I be able to use to do this?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Come on: `:help t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give motions counts even within `d`:

```
d4tp
```

Answer (score 1):

Using visual mode to select and `;` to move to next occurrence makes it easier than counting.

```
vtp;;;x
```